# Do Contract based web services endpoint extensions span tenants?

Tags: acumatica

I'm extending an endpoint to include custom fields on a Bills and Adjustments screen - and I'm wondering if, with multiple (over 10) tenants, do I need to create the same endpoint extension for each tenant?  I ask this because if I try to call an extended endpoint for the tenant where I did NOT set up the extension, it can't find it.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they do not span tenants.

The way you can copy endpoint extensions across tenants is as follows

1. Create a customization project with some name
   [image]
2. Add the web service endpoint definition you have into the project
   [image]
3. Publish the customization to multiple tenants.
   [image]

Now you can propagate your extensions across tenants without recreating them.

Comment: Beauty - thanks, Kyle.

Comment: One further question - is there any way to only publish ONE customization to multiple tenants and let the other customizations publish normally?

Comment: Id publish just the one, select all tenants, and then publish the remainder normally, it would take 2 publishes

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks, Kyle... ;D